# why does using an external monitor eliminate stutter?

Tags: gaming

when playing certain games on my m14x im getting this terrible stutter. However when plugging my laptop into my hdtv via hdmi the game runs smooth as silk with no stuttering!? is there any way to get the same performance on my laptop display.

any help with this would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited help you provided, its going to be hard answering this.

My first suggestion would be that the external display does not run in the same resolution as your main display, but in fact, lower. A lower resolution means less processing power needed, thus less stutter. (note, windows desktop resolution does not equal in-game resolution per se.)

Secondly, there might be 2 graphics cards in your pc, where the HDMI is on the powerful card, and your primary display is not.

Comment: Im sorry about the lack of info im a bit of a noob when it comes to tech. I've attached a pic of my specs. I do have 2 GPU's an Intel HD 3000 and a Nvidia Geforce 555m. If the GPU is the issue is it possible to run the laptop display using the Nvidia card instead of the Intel one?

As always thanks for the reply :)

http://postimg.org/image/4t1pozo1d/ (link to specs)

Comment: So it appears that you indeed have 2 graphics cards, and that your main display uses the build-in one, and a monitor for the accellerated one. You should be able to specify this using the nVidia control panel.

Comment: I've had another look over the control panel and I'm positive there is no way to select the Nvidia GPU as the display adapter for the laptop display!? Setting my laptop screen to clone the TV gets rid of the stutter but without the TV the stuttering still persists. I hope I'm not missing something obvious here xD